# Changing datatype as per column position in Python

Tags: python, position, multiple-columns, dtype

Example data set:

```
data1 = {'Item': ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Rice', 'Wheat'], 'Price': [20.00, 21.00, 19.00, 18.00],'Unit':[34.3, 45.23,12.0,17.2]}   
country1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Now assume I have this data for 5 countries. For all countries I want to convert Price and Unit to integer. However I want to convert them based upon the column position and not column name (as they can have column names in local languages).

Please suggest what can be the best way.

P.S. - I was trying for one dataframe with the below code

```
country1.columns[[1,2]] = country1.columns[[1,2]].astype(int)
```

and received the below error message

```
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your columns as a list and then use indices in the list to set the correct columns.

```
data1 = {'Item': ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Rice', 'Wheat'], 'Price': [20.00, 21.00, 19.00, 18.00],'Unit':[34.3, 45.23,12.0,17.2]}
country1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

cols = country1.columns.tolist()   # or just country1.columns

country1[[cols[1], cols[2]]] = country1[[cols[1], cols[2]]].astype(int)
```

to get

```
    Item  Price  Unit
0  Bread     20    34
1   Milk     21    45
2   Rice     19    12
3  Wheat     18    17
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, with the column name to choose which columns to change.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Item': ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Rice', 'Wheat'], 'Price': [20.00, 
21.00, 19.00, 18.00],'Unit':[34.3, 45.23,12.0,17.2]}
country1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
country1 = country1.astype({'Price': int})
```

If you need multiple columns you can just have multiple keys in the dictionary for the different column titles.

```
country1 = country1.astype({'Price': int})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lucas, however I don't want to do it as per the column names. I have multiple countries and each country may have a different column name, so I have to change the code for all different countries. Instead of that, I'm trying to do it as per the column position.